# PHP Judy array size/count - not what it claims to be?

Tags: php, arrays, count, size

Given two Judy instances, how can the non-static methods size() and count() on any of the two instances be returning what seems to be **the sum of all elements on judy arrays in the same PHP process?**

Is this intentional? Nothing seems to be pointing to this in documentation. Did i miss something?
See Unit test below. testSizeConsistent() fails, others pass, including testIsSizeSum()

```
class JudyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    private $a, $b;

    public function setUp() {

        $this->a = new Judy(Judy::STRING_TO_MIXED);
        $this->b = new Judy(Judy::STRING_TO_MIXED);
    }

    public function testSizeConsistent() {

        // lets populate a 
        $this->a->offsetSet("foo", "bar");
        $this->a->offsetSet("another", "value");

        // b couldn't have possibly grown?
        $this->assertTrue($this->b->size() === 0);

    }

    public function testSizeZero() {

        $this->assertTrue($this->a->size() === 0);
        $this->assertTrue($this->b->size() === 0);

    }

    public function testIsSizeSum() {

        $this->a->offsetSet("foo", "bar");
        $this->a->offsetSet("another", "value");
        $this->b->offsetSet("third", "..");

        $this->assertTrue($this->b->size() === 3);

    }


}
```

( i am using the latest "beta" stability Judy array php module from pecl (pecl.php.net/Judy-0.1.2) and the latest libjudy available in macports ( judy @1.0.5 (devel) ) on OS X Lion )

thanks!
Andras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was definitely a bug. A fix has been released, please give a try:

- http://pecl.php.net/package/Judy/0.1.3
- https://github.com/orieg/php-judy/issues/1